# How virtual function is working in the below code

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public: 
    virtual void gogo(float a){
        printf(" Base :: gogo (int) \n");
    };

    virtual void gogo(char *p){
        printf(" Base :: gogo (int*) \n");
    };
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    virtual void gogo(char *p){
        printf(" Derived ::  (int*)");
    };
};

int main(){
    Derived obj;
    obj.gogo(4.2);
}
```

why the code is giving error. even if the function `gogo` is present in the base class. but while calling it it gives error

Comment: your code doesn't compile, there is no definition for `C::display()`. When I fix this by changing `void display() {` to `void C::display() {` your code works as expected.

Comment: Thanks.. can you clear the second doubt

Comment: When you call `display1()` on a `B`, `A::display1()` is called which in turn will call `A::display()` if it isn't overwritten by a class derived from `A`. When `A::display()` is not declared `virtual` it cannot be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second doubt, that is how `virtual` keyword works. It is used to implement polymorphism.

`display1` is only implemented in the base class `A`. So when `virtual` is not used for `display`,
`obj.display1` ends up calling the `display` of class `A`. But when `virtual` is used for `display`, it will call `display` of class `B`. In this case, the `display` of class `B` has overridden the `display` of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

**case : If `display()` is not declared as virtual:**
`obj.display1()` will call `A::display1()` as its not being overridden by class `B`. As `display1()` is not virtual it will not be checked for dynamic function resolution (@virtual table) and end up calling `A::display()`.

**case : If `display()` is declared as virtual:**
For the Call to `display()`, the object's virtual table (obj : Class B) will be referred for function address and that will lead to the call to `B::display(`).

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtual calls. It's a lookup problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known<sup>[citation needed]</sup> nuance of C++, and has to do with the way multiple overloads interact with inheritance.

Take `virtual` out of the equation, because it's not relevant here. The way inheritance works is by the way *lookup* first examines the class you have, then examines the base if no match was found.

In this example you have three separate functions (even though they all share a name (ish)): `Base::gogo(float)`, `Base::gogo(char*)` and `Derived::gogo(char*)`. You want the compiler to find `Base::gogo(float)`. By calling `gogo` with a `float`, you'd expect it to look for `gogo(float)` in `Derived` then, not finding it, look for `gogo(float)` in `Base` then succeed.

However, instead, it looks for `gogo` (ignoring the argument type!) in `Derived`, finds it, *then* examines all the overloads *in that class*, finds that there isn't one that takes `float`, and fails. And that's it.

**We say that `Derived::gogo(char*)` "hides" `Base::gogo(float)`.**

This is easily solved, though, with a `using` declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public: 
    virtual void gogo(float a){
        printf(" Base :: gogo (int) \n");
    };

    virtual void gogo(char *p){
        printf(" Base :: gogo (int*) \n");
    };
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    using Base::gogo;  // <--- Here!

    virtual void gogo(char *p){
        printf(" Derived ::  (int*)");
    };
};

int main(){
    Derived obj;
    obj.gogo(4.2);
}
```

In this way, we essentially create a `Derived::gogo(float)` with the same contents as `Base::gogo(float)`, without having to write it out again. Consider it a kind of forced inheritance.

Yes, it's a bit weird. But you'll get used to it.

Note that this has nothing to do with `virtual`.

Comment: The code in the question is now very different than when it was first written.

Comment: @P.W Does this answer match how the question is now?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @P.W Good stuff!

Comment: Yeah. So what can one do if his answer is downvoted as it no longer applies to the current version of the question.

Comment: @P.W. If the answer is currently not relevant to the question it can be deleted. But if it has upvotes it can't. And this is why people shouldn't change questions.